# ReferenceError: g is not defined error in Firefox 26.0

Tags: jquery, firefox, flexslider

I'm using Woothemes's jQuery FlexSlider with it's minified jquery version. It's working perfectly in IE-9, Chrome 32, Safari 5.1.7. But when I open it in firefox 26.0 getting `ReferenceError: g is not defined` error in firebug console and this is what happening [image: images are spliting]

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a bug.
I found this on their GitHub page: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/797

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out from https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/958#issuecomment-31643943

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by moving `el.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);` after `function onTouchStart(e) { ... }`

Reference: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/958#issuecomment-31643943

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be fixed with the latest version of Flexslider (v. 2.2.2) but swiping doesn't work for me
in Firefox for Android and it looks like they [haven't fixed *that* yet](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/958) (at least not for all mobile browsers/platforms) so I have found a temporary workaround using jQuery Mobile.

You can include a [custom build of jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) with just the touch events listeners and then listen to swipe events on the Flexslider:

```
$('.flexslider').on({
    swipeleft: function(e) {
        $(this).flexslider('next');
    },
    swiperight: function(e) {
        $(this).flexslider('prev');
    }
});
```

Thought it might be useful in case you guys run into a similar problem. :)